# Atualizando valor de objeto de um Form por uma thread

Tags: c#, winforms, thread

Preciso que 2 labels de meu formulário sejam atualizadas de 1 em 1 segundo, então fiz uma thread no próprio `load` do `Form`:

```
Thread threadUpdate = new Thread(new ThreadStart(UpdateState));
threadUpdate.Start();
```

E o meu método `UpdateState`se encontra da seguinte maneira:

```
private void UpdateState()
    {
        ChangeAutoRestartValue();
        ChangeShellValue();

        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        UpdateState();
    }
```

Ambos métodos dentro do meu `UpdateState` são para atualizar as labels específicas, mas como não é a thread principal que está atualizando o valor dessas labels, ele não permite que isso seja feito.
Como posso atualizar o valor dessas labels utilizando essa thread de atualizar seus valores?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No windows, quem "pinta" os controles na tela é o loop principal de mensagens, em resposta a um evento do windows (WM_PAINT). Por isso, você não consegue atualizar valores nos controles de outra thread.

Somente a thread principal redesenha os controles.

Para contornar esse comportamento, existe um método "Invoke", na classe "Control" da qual herdam todos os controles visuais. Você pode usar esse método para atualizar os dados dos controles.

O método Invoke pede para a thread principal atualizar o valor.

Segue a referência completa do MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Você não deve usar uma thread normal para fazer alterações no Form. Em disso use [BackgroundWorker Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)
. Neste link há um exemplo.